# AsyncStorage singleton in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to make a singleton that will collect all the data that I need around the app. Maybe this approach is wrong, then please correct me.

Right now my Singleton class has simple code:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

export default class DataManager {
    static myInstance = null

    stringsArray = null

    static instance() {
        if (DataManager.myInstance == null) {
            DataManager.myInstance = new DataManager();
        }

        return this.myInstance;
    }

    async getStringsArray() {
      if (this.stringsArray == null) {
        let strings = await AsyncStorage.getItem('stringsArray')
        this.stringsArray = JSON.parse(strings)
      }
        return this.stringsArray
    }

    async setStringsArray(strings) {
        this.stringsArray = strings;
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('stringsArray', JSON.stringify(strings))
    }
}
```

This is how I want to call getters and setters:

```
DataManager.instance().setStringsArray(["abc", "def"])

let stringsArray = DataManager.instance().getStringsArray()
```

Unfortunately if I set something I can not receive it later. I will be glad for some help in that case

Comment: Have you thought about using an Object instead of a class? I think that's the most straightforward way of implementing singleton pattern in JS.

Comment: I will do that . Right now I am trying to clarify my knowledge about JS. Thanks!

Comment: `async` **always** returns a promise. So either `let stringsArray = await ...` or `getStringsArray().then(stringsArray => ...)`

Comment: Also, I would consider this an anti-pattern. The correct way to implement a singleton is `export default new DataManager()` because all modules are already singletons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to store some parameters on your `AsyncStorage` but you do not want to every time import it and use it to save your parameter on phone storage. The common way for react-native apps is using `redux-persist` library. By using this library you are able to save every parameter which is in your redux store. You can read more about it here https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist. You can put every parameter that you want in `redux-persist` `whitelist` and it would be saved on your phone storage.

I hope it would solve your problem. If it was your desired solution please vote me up:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ways to share data between various components or through out App then try redux https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29

Comment: I want to save data locally on the device in every moment. I think redux is something different.

Comment: Well in that case try below two libraries from React Native. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-store, With Native involvement https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shared-preferences